# How to make a Base class for aSyncTask?

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I want to make a base class for some aSyncTasks. I've created an abstract class

```
public abstract class AsyncTaskBase<Params, Progress, Result> extends
    AsyncTask<Params, Progress, Result> {}
```

And two AsyncTask classes which inherit from it aSyncTaskA:

```
public class AsyncTaskA extends AsyncTaskBase<String, String, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) 
    {
        return "A";
    }
}
```

And two AsyncTask classes which inherit from it aSyncTaskB:

```
public class AsyncTaskB extends AsyncTaskBase<String, String, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) 
    {
        return "B";
    }

}
```

In the calling method I call:

```
AsyncTaskBase asyncTask;

// Call aSyncA
asyncTask = new AsyncTaskA();
asyncTask.execute();

// Call aSyncB
asyncTask = new AsyncTaskB();
asyncTask.execute();
```

But I get the following error message

```
05-02 17:00:18.674: E/AndroidRuntime(20120): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Object[] cannot be cast to java.lang.String[]
```

Any ideas what's going wrong

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error is occurring because you haven't passed any params to the `AsyncTask` when you call `#execute()`.  You declare that the `AsyncTask` takes params of type String, but you don't pass in anything at all.

You'll need to call `#execute` like this:

```
asyncTask.execute( (String) null );
```

or this:

```
asyncTask.execute( (String[]) null );
```

or change the generic type for the Params to Void if you want to call `#execute` without any parameters.

---

Also, it's kind of pointless to declare the exact base async that you have demonstrated here.  I assume you'll add something to it at some point, but I think you would be better served by having a base async that at least took care of the generic type parameters for you, i.e. -

```
public abstract class BaseHttpAsync extends AsyncTask<Uri, Void, HttpResult>
```

Declaring `public abstract class AsyncTaskBase<Params, Progress, Result> extends AsyncTask<Params, Progress, Result> {}` effectively gains you no benefits.

Comment: Many thanks David. asyncTask.execute( (String) null ); gave the same error but asyncTask.execute( (String[]) null ); WORKS. Really appreciate the extra info about the using VOID for passing in no parameters.  And really appreciate the extra info about the generic types, very very useful to me to get me head around this.

Comment: Glad it was helpful. Not sure why `asyncTask.execute( (String) null )` wouldn't work for you.  Both of them worked for me when I tested it.